Accessibility Issue: Multiple Links on Same Line in Flutter RichText
Steps to reproduce

Create a RichText widget with multiple TextSpan or WidgetSpan elements, each representing a clickable link.

Wrap each link in a Semantics widget to ensure accessibility support.

Add GestureDetector to handle onTap events for each link.

Test using a screen reader (TalkBack on Android or VoiceOver on iOS).
Code sample:


MergeSemantics(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                children: [
                  const TextSpan(
                    text:
                        'Android is a mobile operating system based on a modified version of the ',
                  ),
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: Semantics(
                      label: 'Linux kernel',
                      button: true,
                      //link: true,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("Link 1 tapped!");
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Linux kernel',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const TextSpan(
                    text: ' and other ',
                  ),
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: Semantics(
                      label: 'open-source',
                      button: true,
                      //link: true,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print(" link 2 tapped!");
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'open-source',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const TextSpan(
                    text: ' software.',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

Expected results
Whole content should be readable in a single tap and each link should be clickable.
Actual results
The screen reader only selects or announces the first link consistently.
The second link is often skipped or merged with surrounding text, making it inaccessible.

Try using recognizer in TextSpan instead of using WidgetSpan and GestureDetector
MergeSemantics(
        child: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
        children: [
          const TextSpan(
            text:
                'Android is a mobile operating system based on a modified version of the ',
          ),
          TextSpan(
              text: 'Linux kernel',
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () {
                  print("Link 1 tapped!");
                }),
          const TextSpan(
            text: ' and other ',
          ),
          TextSpan(
              text: 'open-source',
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () {
                  print(" link 2 tapped!");
                }),
          const TextSpan(
            text: ' software.',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

